# How to fill a rectangular hole with an even amount of vertices on either side?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I tried crating faces but it left missing edges. In the end I was left with all the right lines but there was no vertex in the center.

[image]

Here's a follow up image in case you're wondering what I mean. Notice how there's no vertex in the center.

[image]

Comment: can't you just create an edge by selecting two opposite vertices and pressing f, then subdivide it once to get a vertex in the middle?

Comment: tried subdividing, it didnt work. In fact it kinda made a mess. It created a vertice in the mid point of every edge, but that's all. It didn't even make any edges.

Comment: An addendum to the answers: after filling the grid, it may be necessary to flip or recalculate the normals in the newly restored part of the mesh.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If both sides have the same number of vertices, you can quickly do this by using the *Grid Fill* tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> *> Grid Fill*) and tweaking the operator settings. A Span and Offset of 2 should do the trick.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

It is recommended to use **Grid Fill** tool (*Mesh > Faces > Grid Fill*). I would like to give some further tips for it:

- The initial connection pattern depends on the active vertex. In this case, you can avoid additional tweakings on *Span* and *Offset* by simly keep the "corner" vertex active before filling. See comparison below:

With **non-corner** vertex active:

[image]

With **corner vertex** active:

[image]

- You can also just select a pair of connected vertices of opposite side, then fill, which can also provide a one-stop result.

[image]

- All in all, the easiest way to this is: In **Edge Select** mode, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> on any border edge, which will select the complete loop, then operate Grid Fill, which can well handle it at most time (especially for regular holes like this) regardless the active element concern.

[image]

Comment: Oh my GOSH that tidbit about the corner vertex being selected for grid fill to work properly has finally put hours of googling to and end.   Thank you for your comprehensive and concise answer.