# How can I fix these faces?

Tags: modeling

I messed up at some point during modeling and had to reconnect some edges but now I don't have the vertices I need to continue. How can I fix the faces so it fits the rest of the model?

[image]

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9252/599