# Fix or make new?

Tags: mesh

I am trying to extrude a 2D floorplan.

However, I somehow managed to mess it up. For some reason, some faces are missing.

I have uploaded my blender file here:
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36771

Is there a way to easily fix that, or should I just start from scratch hoping I won't make the same mistake again?

[image]

Comment: Try grid fill: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9252/599

Comment: By extruding with `Snap during Transform` turned on you can easily get [this](http://i.imgur.com/35AeHp8.jpg). The ngon on the right is at your choise, either converting in to quads (creating loopcuts in the wall, so adding geometry), or leaving as is, if ngons are good for you there.

Comment: Does something like that happen to you advanced users, too, and I should learn to deal with it, or do you think I should start thinking about the logic behind what I am doing? :-)

Comment: It's very general question. To be short - it happens to many artists and you should think about the logic.

Comment: @tmighty, yes things like what you have described in this question, and the other asked earlier, happens to advanced users, too. Except as users gain experience and become advanced users, they learn to modify work practices and avoid some of these issues, on the one hand, and on the other, they learn to fix the mistakes once they are made. These mistakes are just the tuition in the "School of hard knocks".