# why i cannot add fill grid

Tags: mesh

With the sphere and top edge selected i want to add the grid fill but im getting this error  **Select 2 edge loops**

[image]

[image]

How to grid fill. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: You need an even number of vertices, I think.

Comment: @OmarAhmad I have added a single verts to above mesh on top to make it even number and it works Great. But if i take a default circle and added grid fill it works with the odd number also

Comment: Atek, are you sure? I've tried to add a circle with an odd number of vertices (9 and 11): the grid fill request gives an error.

Comment: It might work if you select a pair of loops on opposite sides of the circle instead of selecting the whole circle, but triangles will be introduced---try it. I recommend you check this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9252/how-to-fill-a-rectangular-hole-with-an-even-amount-of-vertices-on-either-side#answer-9254) by Leon Cheung.

Comment: @atek It's not working with odd number of vertices however you create it, new circle or old one. If you don't care if there will be triangles you can just use Alt+F it will fill nicely the surface with triangles. You can also turn on Mesh: F2 addon, select one of the edges, press F few times and get most quads and one trinagle.

Comment: Deselect two vertices, on opposite sides. This will allow the grid fill to know where it can start and end.